# W3C error on css

Tags: opacity, css

I am getting 2 error messages when I run my .css file through W3C and do not understand what is wrong. 
Does anyone have any suggestions.

Here is the error message:

```
117  img.floatright  Parse Error opacity=70)
79   Property -moz-border-radius is an unknown vendor extension
```

Corresponding line on my .css are:

```
 79:   -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
117:  filter:alpha(opacity=70);
```

Answer (score 3):

Properties starting with `-` are vendor prefix properties. They are used to experimental features which might become standard (without the `-moz-`, `-webkit-`, etc) in the future. They are not valid. `border-radius` has become standard and Firefox no longer supports `-moz-border-radius` as it has moved to the standard.

`filter` is a proprietary extension to CSS invented by Microsoft and used in older versions of Internet Explorer. It is not valid.

Comment: You might still keep `-moz-border-radius`, since it does not harm, and some odd people might still use Firefox 3 or older, which only recognize this nonstandard name. The W3C CSS Validator has (under “More Options”) an option that makes vendor extensions reported as warnings and not errors (to make it easier to analyze real errors in CSS code).